# How can I get the Icon of a token?

Tags: token, accountinfo

I want to show a list of Tokens and can't figure out where to find the url to the token icon. It does not seem to be in the meta data like for NFTs.
https://explorer.solana.com/address/orcaEKTdK7LKz57vaAYr9QeNsVEPfiu6QeMU1kektZE/metadata

Seems its coming from the TokenList
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-labs/token-list/main/assets/mainnet/orcaEKTdK7LKz57vaAYr9QeNsVEPfiu6QeMU1kektZE/logo.png

Do I need to parse the Solana token list and match it to the Symbol of the AccountInfo data? Or is there an easier way to do it?
https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
string tokenIconUrl = $"https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list/blob/main/assets/mainnet/{tokenMint}/logo.png?raw=true";
```

But seems to be old way of doing things and should use the meta data account instead according to this:
https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list

Answer (score -1):

The "token-list" repo is old and outdated since summer 2022.

It has been superceded by a new API. You can get the token metadata (including the image) programmatically.

When I get home from work I will show you some sample code here.

Comment: Thanks, i checked the meta data, but could not figure out yet how to deserialize it and looks like the orca token for example does not have a URL set in the meta data. At least from what i can see in the explorer: https://explorer.solana.com/address/orcaEKTdK7LKz57vaAYr9QeNsVEPfiu6QeMU1kektZE/metadata

Comment: @JonasH. what is the token address?

Comment: orcaEKTdK7LKz57vaAYr9QeNsVEPfiu6QeMU1kektZE